# Can we build a sling in space to shoot a ship to Mars faster?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, fuel

Is this concept covered somewhere I'm curious about resistance and tension and velocity in space versus tons of chemical fuels? If I've missed that can you point me to it?

Comment: **If** my back of the envelope calculations are correct (a big 'if'), the radius of the 'sling' is 10 Km and the final speed required is 3.6 Km/s (for a basic Hohman transfer from Earth to Mars) the Gs experienced in the craft would be ..132. So even a relatively long tether, will require high Gs (and a very strong tether). The numbers don't make it seem so easy..

Comment: @AndrewThompson But, we could conceivably launch the people up separately and use that to launch the bulk of the ship, no?

Comment: Sure, but know we have 3+ Earth surface to orbit launches. 1 for the ship, one (or probably more) for the sling, and one for the crew that must still reach 3.6 Km/s. Plus the main ship would have be built to withstand 132 Gs! Once you boil 'conceivably' down to the raw numbers, it doesn't seem to offer any benefits.